# How intensive on resources are workflows in wait?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm thinking about using a workflow that could run and then wait for a week or so and rerun.  What is the workflow doing while in that wait period?  I've shied away from doing this previously because of my assumption that it isn't a best practice to have workflows running constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows are based on timer jobs. Therefore if you keep the workflow waiting it will go into hibernation state. The performances of the application pool will not be largely affected at its first sight. But it keeps necessary resources locked to it.

Also these types of workflows will run slower.

I would suggest splitting the long workflow into two workflows and store necessary intermediate data in the list item it self and write a timer job which checks the time since previous workflow started, if that is over than 1 week, start the second workflow.

But you better consider the number of workflows will run at a given time. If that is low, I would say go with one workflow.